# Why am I getting the same results on every std::nexttoward function call

Tags: c++

Why does the following code returns the same number on every `std::nexttoward` function call?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);

    auto foo = 0.00000000000011134;
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        foo = std::nexttoward(foo, 1.0);
        std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/551b6e2b867b2f3b

None of the flags mentioned [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) (FE_OVERFLOW, FE_UNDERFLOW и FE_INEXACT) are set.

Answer (score 4):

This is because floating point format is generally oriented to preserving a certain number of ***significant*** digits.

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
```

Using a `std::ios::fixed` format with numerically small values forces the formatted output to insert a bunch of non-significant "leading" zeroes (after the decimal point). That's what you really see in the output of your test program. This comes at the expense of truncating the actual significant digits, when the I/O library has to chop everything off after the fixed `precision()`.

After removing the `std::ios::fixed` formatting flag (and keeping `precision()`), the output becomes what you expect (tested myself with gcc 7.2.1, [and reproduced on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27d8df3af387d51b)):

```
1.1134e-13
1.1134000000000001e-13
1.1134000000000002e-13
1.1134000000000003e-13
1.1134000000000005e-13
1.1134000000000006e-13
1.1134000000000007e-13
1.1134000000000008e-13
1.113400000000001e-13
1.1134000000000011e-13
1.1134000000000012e-13
```

...etc

Move that decimal point thirteen positions to the left (that's what `e-13` says), and see for yourself what happens after `std::ios::fixed` chops off everything after the specified number of digits.